# cURL PUT Request with Nextcloud / owncloud API

Tags: php, curl, owncloud, nextcloud

I tried to update an existing Nextcloud user through their API. When I do it directly via shell it works

```
curl -u user:pass -X PUT "https://example.org/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/admin" -H "OCS-APIRequest: true" -d key="quota" -d value="5GB"
```

But when I try to do it via PHP with the following code it always returns "failure 997"

```
$url = 'https://' . $ownAdminname . ':' . $ownAdminpassword . '@example.org/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/admin';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$fields = array("quota" => "5GB");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'OCS-APIRequest: true'
    ));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "Response: ".$response;
```

Comment: You're not including `value` in the second. You should specify what response you are getting.

Comment: I do ( `$fields = array("quota" => "11GB")`)  ), it's just a bit misleading, that I use 5GB in the first example and 11GB in the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the cURL command and the PHP code you pasted lies in a [poorly designed user provisioning API](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/configuration/user/user_provisioning_api.html).

Using these cURL arguments:

```
-d key="quota" -d value="5GB"
```

... is not equivalent to the fields you're posting:

```
$fields = array("quota" => "5GB");
```

... but rather:

```
$fields = array(
    'key' => 'quota',
    'value' => '5GB',
);
```

The explanation for the `997` code you're getting can be found in https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/v10.0.3/apps/provisioning_api/lib/Users.php#L269-L272: since there's no "`key`" *key* in the data submitted (`$parameters['_put']['key']` will evaluate as `null`) and hence the error.